# Subjunctive Trigger Phrase with Passive Construction (Ser)

Tags: subjuntivo, voz-pasiva

In the following sentence, why is it grammatical to use the passive voice and not the subjunctive tense.

> Es muy probable que fueron creados por él.
>
> ---
>
> It's very likely that they were created by him.

I thought that "Es muy probable que..." always triggers the subjunctive. However, my Spanish professor told me that the previous sentence is correct. Why?

I reviewed my subjunctive tense notes but couldn't find anything on this. Thank you.

Comment: As a native speaker, It doesn't seem idiomatic to me. I agree with your rule.

Comment: I would also use the subjunctive: "fueran" or "hayan sido"...

Comment: As a native speaker what I would say is "Es muy probable que **fueran** creados por el"

Comment: Native speaker here and that sounds perfectly idiomatic to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only case where both indicative and subjunctive are accepted is that in which "es (muy) probable que" is replaced with "(muy) probablemente". However, the subjunctive will sound less probable than the indicative:

- Es (muy) probable que fueran / hayan sido creados por él.
- (Muy) Probablemente fueron / fueran/hayan sido creados por él.